Oh no! Something has gone wrong when I cancel the installation of a package
This error occurs when I cancel the installation of a package.


Is it a regular update or a upgrade to another version of Ubuntu?

Open a virtual terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F3. Then log in with your username and password.
Configure the partially configured packages with
sudo dpkg --configure -a

Install all the updates with the commands
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

Finally, restore the GUI with
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^

Please note that the ^ is necessary in the last command.
Then reboot with the command reboot, and you should get back your GUI.

I've tried pressing the button Ctrl + Alt + F3  but the terminal doesn't appear

@Yumi Please try Ctrl + Alt + function_key + F3

@I've done it but the terminal doesn't show up

@Yumi I am unsure why this is happening. Consider fresh installing 24.04
